# Scanning Barcodes using Redlaser sdk

Tags: iphone, barcode-scanner

I am using redlaser sdk for scanning the barcode of products. I want to get the  details of the scanned product like name, price etc. But now i am getting only the TIN number of the products while scanning. How can i retrieve the product details from that TIN number within the iPhone code. I have checked the Redlaser iPhone application and there product details are showing  after scanning. RedLaser iPhone application uses different services to collect price information (including Google and TheFind.com). How can i collect the product details from this TIN number i am getting from? Kindly give a solution for getting the details.

Thanks in advance for your replies,

Comment: why u use this sdk is not for distribution purpose. it is only testing purpose.

Comment: we have registered in redlaser and have downloaded the sdk and integrated..is it not possible to distribute even though?

Comment: if u have license version then u use it for distribution otherwise no

Comment: Thanks Ron, i am using the licensed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this link "http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html#intro"  that you have provided for getting the product details using TIN number.  You can implement the corresponding API in the application.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot display all the details of a product by simply getting the TIN number.you have two options to achieve this(as I know)

1.You should have a database which ha details of product for perticular set of TIN numbers
   which is updated regularly.

2.You should use web services i.e. connecting to website to fetch details of a particular 
   TIN.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

http://www.upcdatabase.com/xmlrpc.asp this is the api link for upc codes.